# How to make a transition effect that just perform like css transition?

Tags: jquery, css-transitions

I want to make a quite common transition effect when the mouse hovers over a `content`div, the background image of that `content`div light up and the `info`header inside the div slide in from the left as well. However, since I have 12 of them, I can't afford to name each and every one of them a class/id, so I can't (or I don't know the right way) to do them in css.

Then I tried jquery, and used

```
$(".container>.content").hover(function() { 

        $(this).find('.info').animate({
            "right": 0,
            "opacity": 1
        },200);
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            "opacity": 1
        },200);
    }, function() {
        $(this).find('.info').animate({
            "right": $(this).outerWidth(),
            "opacity": 0
        },200);
        $(this).find('img').animate({
            "opacity": 0
        },200);

    });
```

( I have 12 of the `container` div and each of them has one `content` and one `info` class)

which basically are two sets of animations for the mouseover and mouseleave.

The problem is that, unlike css transitions, where after the mouse enter/leave the area, the effect will reverse at the current frame, the animation in jquery has to wait until the entire animation is over, which doesn't really work in my case.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you can do that fairly easily with CSS transitions and use of `:hover`. See **[this working model](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/EWA2w/)**.

CSS:

```
.content {
    font-size: 1.2em;
    padding: 5em;
}
.content .info {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(-100vw);
    transition: opacity .4s, transform .4s;
}
.content img {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .4s;
}
.content:hover .info {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
}
.content:hover img {
    opacity: 1
}
```

Comment: did you consider that OP may need to support older browsers?

Comment: @charlietfl In his original post, he wrote: "However, since I have 12 of them, I can't afford to name each and every one of them a class/id, so I can't (or I don't know the right way) to do them in css.  Then I tried jquery...." That does not seem to be a concern for him.

Comment: good point, just throwing it out there since IE didn't start support until IE10

Comment: @RyanMitchell@charlietfl Thanks, I thought `.content:hover img` would change all `img` class, but it looks like it only changes the one being hovered on. Also, thanks for the call on opacity, and yes that was not too much of a concern now.

Comment: @YonL It does select all of the `img` elements within currently hovered `.content` elements, so it's possible you might need a more refined selector if you have multiple images inside your `.content`s and don't want them all to be animated. Depending on your structure, you may want to use `.content:hover img:first-child` or `.content:hover img:first-of-type`. (See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type).) A lot of options out there.

Comment: @RyanMitchell Yeah. It was the "currently hoverd" which got me confused, I thought all `img` class would be selected regardless of the hover. Currently only one image is contained in each `content` so it works for now. Thanks for the link. It is a good reference.